# Connection refused on port 4000

Tags: networking

Trying to run Jekyll on a Google Compute Engine VM instance. It runs a server on port 4000. I have created a firewall rule to allow incoming traffic from this port, but all my connections get refused for some reason. What else should I be looking at?

Comment: Is Jekyll running? Is it listening on port 4000?

Comment: solution: jekyll serve --host 0.0.0.0